# How to specify a Windows Desktop platform with Facebook App

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have written a windows desktop app  (WinForms) in VS2010 .Net C#, which runs on Vista through to Win 8.   I am now looking to adding facebook photo uploading functionality to the app using the facebook c# sdk.

The problem I have is with Facebook Developer where I have started the process of registering my desktop app as a Facebook app so that I can then have it reviewed and then ultimately be given permissions to upload photos, but on the Facebook Developer website there is no option to choose 'Windows desktop client' (or similar) as my app platform.

Without assigning a platform I cannot progress to submitting my app to Facebook for review.
Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: You can specify "Windows App" as a platform in the App's setting...

Comment: Thanks. But when I select this, it then requires me to enter a Windows Store ID, in other words it is only allowing Windows Store apps, not plain old standard Windows apps.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @user3658234 Have you finally succeed in registering you app on facebook? If so what helped?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you have to choose the "Website" option.

Even if your app is a desktop app, the login process happens in web (normally using a web browser).