# Facebook Marketing Api - lead retrial - no access

Tags: api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm a developer in a data solutions company. My boss asked me retriever leads from our current
campaign on Facebook.

I created and registered an app שמג wrote a short python script that is running on my local machine and is using the python sdk to pull data from the service.

When I pull the lead data I can only see a lead that was created by my manger, she is registered to the same adaccount.

After further investigation I saw this :

"Starting in v9.0, you will not be able to retrieve leads if your app is in Dev Mode. For testing purposes, Dev Mode app users can access leads submitted by someone with a role in that same app. See App Roles. Apps in Live Mode continue to have access to all leads."

At this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/

When I go to Marketing Api/Settings on App page I see this :

Ads API Access Level:development
Possible reasons for current access level:
App unapproved for "Ads Management Standard Access"

How can I change the Access Level ?

Also, the app type is **Business**, I vaguely remember that I read that business app get basic access automatically.

Help will be appropriated
Roy

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with it too. As you pointed out, now the application needs to be approved in advance to get all the leads back.
the change from development mode to live mode is done through the development environment of the facebook application itself.

Go to developers-app home: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Add this to the end of your url: /app-review/submissions

Follow all the steps, basically you need to describe the whole operation and why you need the permissions you requested by text and screencasts, do this and wait for the feedback of them.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the process of App review it is requested to add a **platform** to the app, this is performed in the settings->basic window.

My app is a *desktop* app and the platform options did non suit a desktop app. The other platform options included uploading an app to an app store, something that for some is not trivial.

I noticed [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769185/how-to-specify-a-windows-desktop-platform-with-facebook-app), I choose the **Website** platform and was approved.